# Code works locally, but not in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

still kinda new here so bear with me as I'm new to JS and kinda teaching it to myself.

So I've been trying to script a simple Rock Paper Scissors game, and I have gotten it to work locally on my machine, but for the life of me cannot figure out why it will not work on JSFiddle. I started writing it out in JSFiddle first, but after I got frustrated with JSLint deeming it valid but having the game hang somewhere in my JS i decided to just move it to notepad and try it locally. Well, it works yet I can't figure out why it doesn't like fiddle. Maybe you guys could shed some light on this for me

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var ties = 0;
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;

// randInt returns a random integer between 0 and 2
function randInt() {return Math.floor(Math.random()*3);}

function msgAlert(msg, player, comp) {
    var outcome = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];

    if (msg === "tie") {
        alert("Tie!\n" + "Player: " + outcome[player] + "\n" + "Computer: " +     outcome[comp]);
    }

    if (msg === "win") {
        alert("You won!\n" + "Player: " + outcome[player] + "\n" + "Computer: " +     outcome[comp]);
    }          

    if (msg === "lose") {
        alert("You lost!\n" + "Player: " + outcome[player] + "\n" + "Computer: " +     outcome[comp]);
    }
}

function updateScore(result) {
    var tieElement = document.getElementById("tie");
    var winElement = document.getElementById("win");
    var loseElement = document.getElementById("lose");

    if (result === "tie") {
        ties++;
        tieElement.innerText = ties;
    }

    if (result === "win") {
        wins++;
        winElement.innerText = wins;
    }

    if (result === "lose") {
        losses++;
        loseElement.innerText = losses;
    }
}

function hand(player) {
    var comp = randInt();

    if (player === comp) {
        updateScore("tie");
        msgAlert("tie", player, comp);
    }

    /* Rock Conditions */
    if (player === 0 && comp === 1) {
        updateScore("lose");
        msgAlert("lose", player, comp);
    }

    if (player === 0 && comp === 2) {
        updateScore("win");
        msgAlert("win", player, comp);
    }

    /* Paper Conditions */
    if (player === 1 && comp === 0) {
        updateScore("win");
        msgAlert("win", player, comp);
    }

    if (player === 1 && comp === 2) {
        updateScore("lose");
        msgAlert("lose", player, comp);
    }

    /* Scissors Conditions */
    if (player === 2 && comp === 0) {
        updateScore("lose");
        msgAlert("lose", player, comp);
    }

    if (player === 2 && comp === 1) {
        updateScore("win");
        msgAlert("win", player, comp);
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor=tan>
    <H1 align=center>Let's play Rock Paper Scissors!</H1>
    <H2>Instructions</H2>
    <p>Click a button to choose what to throw</p>
    <p id="buttons">
        <input type="button" value="Rock" onclick="hand(0);" />
        <input type="button" value="Paper" onclick="hand(1);" />
        <input type="button" value="Scissors" onclick="hand(2);" /> 
    </p>
    <h3>Scoreboard:</h3>
    <ul id="scoreboard">
        <li>
            Wins: <span id="win">0</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            Losses: <span id="lose">0</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            Ties: <span id="tie">0</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[This sample code at the jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/aFeJaME/1/edit)

Comment: @ClaudioSantos that's exactly **why** I asked the link to the non-working fiddle. How else would one answer such a question?

Comment: Sorry about that
JSFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/kr3PU/

Comment: Fine, you both now have a new reason to move to jsbin.com, that code works perfectly there. :D

Comment: On the jsfiddle sidebar, where it says Framework and Extensions, change `onLoad` to `No wrap-in <body>`

Comment: Point to jsbin.com :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work in the jsFiddle, you have to set the upper left setting in jsFiddle to "No Wrap - in <body>".

When you have it set to `onload`, that puts all your code in an onload handler and nothing is declared globally (it's declared inside the onload handler function).  Since nothing is declared globally, the `hand()` function is not global and won't work when called directly from your HTML because it must be global in scope to be reachable via a direct call from your HTML.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/E9aFy/

Comment: Thank you so much for your input and explanation. Helped me out

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly at jsbin.com, [take a look](http://jsbin.com/aFeJaME/2/edit) and enable the javascript (if don't)